# Warning: Trying to access array offset on value of type bool in usuarios.controlador.php on line 24

Tags: php

tengo un problema y es que me aparece este error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí].

Warning: Trying to access array offset on value of type bool in C:\xampp\htdocs\inventario\controladores\usuarios.controlador.php on line 24

A la hora de digitar un usuario que no se encuentra en la base de datos, he cambiado todo el código, pero sigue igual

Este es el código de la función que he tomado de un proyecto que me parece interesante.

```
static public function ctrIngresoUsuario(){

    if(isset($_POST["ingUsuario"])){

        if(preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/', $_POST["ingUsuario"])){

            $encriptar = crypt($_POST["ingPassword"], '$2a$07$asxx54ahjppf45sd87a5a4dDDGsystemdev$');
            $tabla = "usuarios";
            $item = "usuario";
            $valor = $_POST["ingUsuario"];
            $respuesta = ModeloUsuarios::MdlMostrarUsuarios($tabla, $item, $valor);

            if($respuesta["usuario"] == $_POST["ingUsuario"] && $respuesta["password"] == $encriptar){
                if($respuesta["estado"] == 1){
                    $_SESSION["iniciarSesion"] = "ok";
                    $_SESSION["id"] = $respuesta["id"];
                    $_SESSION["nombre"] = $respuesta["nombre"];
                    $_SESSION["usuario"] = $respuesta["usuario"];
                    $_SESSION["foto"] = $respuesta["foto"];
                    $_SESSION["perfil"] = $respuesta["perfil"];

                    /*=============================================
                    REGISTRAR FECHA PARA SABER EL ÚLTIMO LOGIN
                    =============================================*/

                    date_default_timezone_set('America/Bogota');
                    $fecha = date('Y-m-d');
                    $hora = date('H:i:s');
                    $fechaActual = $fecha.' '.$hora;
                    $item1 = "ultimo_login";
                    $valor1 = $fechaActual;
                    $item2 = "id";
                    $valor2 = $respuesta["id"];
                    $ultimoLogin = ModeloUsuarios::mdlActualizarUsuario($tabla, $item1, $valor1, $item2, $valor2);

                    if($ultimoLogin == "ok"){
                        echo '<script>
                            window.location = "inicio";
                        </script>';
                    }                                       
                }else{
                    echo '<br>
                        <div class="alert alert-danger">El usuario aún no está activado</div>';
                }       
            }else{
                echo '<br><div class="alert alert-danger">Error al ingresar, vuelve a intentarlo</div>';
            }
        }   
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

La respuesta era complicada pero básica, lo único que había que hacer era agregar una línea para preguntar si es array o no y en caso de que sea seguir con el código.

Hay que corregir la linea que pide en ingreso en mi caso fue la 24

```
if(is_array($respuesta) && $respuesta["usuario"] == $_POST["ingUsuario"] && $respuesta["password"]== $encriptar){
```